# How to simply change,get or set any attribute in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dom

I need to convert my jquery application into React completely and don't know how to get, set any attribute in React. I'm doing it with jquery but no idea how to start it with react. Looked at some examples but didn't find any appropriate solution to my question.

```
class App extends React.Component {
            changeAttr() {
                $('[data-correctans]').attr('data-correctans','chnaged_status');
            }
            render () {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <div data-correctans="staus">Hi I am new to react, Need to do some DOM manipulation!!</div>
                        <button onClick={() => this.changeAttr()}>Change attr!</button>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }                      
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Make use of refs or use state to reflect changes in dom.read this https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: This is an example where you store the state in the DOM. With React you don't store the state in the DOM. I would suggest to rethink your approach.

Comment: @Kunukn where did i store the state, sorry i didn't get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your perspective of how you see your web app. `React.Component` only reacts to the state and props. React is very easy to learn, so reading the official tutorial may help you a lot (taking less than several hours for the basic part).

```
changeAttr() {
    // $('[data-correctans]').attr('data-correctans','chnaged_status');
    this.setState({ data_correctans: 'changed_status' });
}
render () {
    // the followings are JSX, not the HTML, so you can use JS code within { }
    return (
        <div>
            <div data-correctans="{this.state.data_correctans}">Hi I am new to react, Need to do some DOM manipulation!!</div>
            <button onClick={() => this.changeAttr()}>Change attr!</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Basically i know how state works, but it means that for every attribute change i need to set and define its state which is not feasible enough for complex applications.

Comment: Oh, if it was the matter of complexity, I suggest you take a look at Redux as a global state management. If you are dealing with a complex application, Redux (or Mobx) is something you need to get.